# Storing and using facebook's refresh token in Identity as a service (IDaaS)

Tags: amazon-cognito, auth0, okta, refresh-token, identity-management

We're planning to use IDaaS for better identity management. We are comparing functionalities between Okta, Auth0, and AWS Cognito.
However, Facebook provides a way to [refresh user token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/). They also have an option for [extending page token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension/). My question is if I use any of IDaaS or identity management system, can I use those functionalities.

I know I can get a refresh token from Okta or Auth0 and use it to get access token. But could not find any way to retrieve or use the refresh token from Facebook. Am I missing anything?

I have added Facebook as Social Identity Provider. I can log in using via facebook account. My applications do not know about Facebook's App Id and secret. Is it possible to use the facebooks refresh token functionalities via IDaaS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Okta's Identity Provider API to get the Facebook access token issued for a user during authentication.

https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/idps#identity-provider-social-authentication-token-model

You can then use it to call Facebook APIs to get a refresh token that you can then store within Okta as a custom attribute on the (idp)user profile.

I'm assuming that you want to use the FB refresh/access token to get additional data from Facebook. Is that your use case, or is it primarily about keeping the user logged in to facebook? More detail on the use case can help me provide more relevant information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is primarily about keeping the user logged in to Facebook. And, I do not store facebooks app id and app secret across multiple application. Is it doable?

Comment: From the Facebook documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/

It seems like you need the client ID and secret in order to get a refresh token. As that's a FB requirement I don't think there's a way to get around that.

Why do you need to keep the user logged in to Facebook? You can have them logged into the app by using Okta refresh tokens instead.

Do you want to keep them logged in to enable more interactions with FB apis after authentication? If so i'd be really curious to learn what you're doing here.

Comment: We are also using Facebook Business Manager api to upload a post on behalf of the client. Before the post is uploaded there are multiple approval processes to go through. Not sure, refresh token will be any help on this